# JPA: Mapping table which contains some foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have 4 tables:

1. **Users** - contains user data
2. **Moduls** - dictionary, with unique "Module's names"
3. **Modules_Access_Rules** - dictionary of all "Modul's rules"
4. **j_Users_Modules_Rule** - table which links three previous (look at the diagram)

[image]

I have an entity which contains `Set<Modul>` **->** `Modul` linked with `User` like `@OneToMany`,`Modul` contains  `Set<ModuleRule>` **->** also `@OneToMany`.
I try to use `Spring-Data-JPA-Mapping` to linking `Users` with `Modules` and with `Modules Rules`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private int id;


  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(
        name = "j_Users_Modules_Rule",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name="id_Module",referencedColumnName="id"),
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name="id_rule",referencedColumnName="id")
        }
  )
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Module> authorities;

  // Getters and Setters

}
```

, Module entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Modules")
public class Module implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(
        name = "j_Users_Modules_Rule",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name="id_Module",referencedColumnName="id"),
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name="id_rule",referencedColumnName="id")
        }
  )
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<ModuleRule> moduleRules;

  //Getters and Setters

}
```

and ModuleRule entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Modules_access_rules")
public class ModuleRule implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name; 

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

I correctly (by business requirement) get **User** with **Modules** and **ModuleRules**, but when I save `User` the result is incorrect in **j_Users_Modules_Rule** table:

[image]

I understand that I join tables twice(*User* -> *Module*, *Module* -> *ModuleRule*), but I don't know how `save` value correct in **j_Users_Modules_Rule** table.

> I have not found a solution yet and use `Spring JdbcTemplate` (process a Result Set use `ResultSetExtractor`).

The **query**:

```
SELECT 
    U.*, J.id_Module, M.name AS name_Module, 
    J.id_Rule, R.name AS name_Rule 
FROM 
    dbo.[Users] U (nolock) 
JOIN 
    dbo.j_Users_Modules_Rule J (nolock) ON U.id = J.id_User   
JOIN 
    dbo.Modules M (nolock) ON M.id = J.id_Module 
JOIN 
    dbo.Modules_Access_Rules R (nolock) ON R.id = J.id_Rule
```

Comment: j_Users_Modules_Rule does not seem to be a join table as it contains other fields too..

Comment: @codeLover - I think about  creating `j_Users_Modules_Rule` as an entity, but I don't want to cash  `j_Users_Modules_Rule`-entity in the app.

Comment: You can do lazy loading in that case..

Comment: @codeLover - "I don't want to cash `j_Users_Modules_Rule`-entity in the app" -> I mean that If I want update `j_Users_Modules_Rule` table, I will have to cash `j_Users_Modules` unique id.